# run file python in php non block

Tags: php, python, loading, blocking

i have this file php, i want run file python in this php:
but file php blocking, and page loading for ever

```
<?php 
$result = shell_exec('1.py ');
echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

and is my code 1.py :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en& continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail&service=mail&   flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys('mygmail@gmail.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.RveJvd.snByac").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('mypassword')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.RveJvd.snByac").click()
time.sleep(3)
a=driver.title
#aa= driver.page_source

if 'Inbox' in a :
    print('login good')

else :
    print('not login')
```

when i run my php file in  localhost/1.php
is blocking in

```
$result = shell_exec('1.py ');
```

and Dont run

```
echo "Hello world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the following PHP:

```
<?php
Header("Content-Type: text/plain");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print shell_exec('1.py');
?>
```

This way you can see if the command hits some other problems.

Comment: in the code you shared, there's two " ; " closing the echo line

Comment: yes, relax. using the full path was to test if the file was in a place that didn't have the right permissions.

I'm updating the php code to test if you got any other error

Comment: tanx for answer but is not work.please check my script python and php in same folder and run..you see if id gmail and password gmail is good or wrong script not working

Comment: any update you can give me here? really want to help you @netdevil